# ESP8266 not load a new sketch

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm new to Arduino and I'm doing a proof of concept with ESP8266.
First I made the connection and I was able to send AT commands, then I was able to upload a sketch to update the firmware of the device and based on the IDE example I could run a Webserver in it.

Now I want to update the firmware again but I can not anymore. If I connect the board in normal mode the loaded firmware is initialized but if I connect in flash mode (GPIO0 to GND) I can not update the firmware as if I could do it the previous time.
I am working with an external power supply (12v connected to an arduino board one to get 3.3V stable) and a FTDI to USB adapter for TX and RX.

When I try to load a new sketch the IDE return "no existe o tu placa no esta conectada"

Comment: Does the port being showed in IDE ?. Also, can you post the complete question in English?

Comment: the port is shown, how I published the firmware is working and I can read the logs, that mean I have connectivity (I guess). Well the only not english message is like "board not exists or not connected" thanks in advance

Comment: You can't update firmware in that mode... GPIO0 must be free.. Dunno why, but had same issue..